# How to lock without synchronize an ArrayList full of Objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

For my Assignment, I have to create a program, which always has an ArrayList(Size 10) full of Sudoku-Objects, and if there are less then 7, a Thread is started to create Sudoku-Object to make it full again.

Here is the Code which always checks if there are less than 7, Sudoku-Object saved:

```
alleSpiele = new ArrayList<SudokuSpiel>();
lock.lock();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    alleSpiele.add(new SudokuSpiel());
}
while (running) {
            SudokuSpiel sudp = alleSpiele.get(0);
            sudp.ausgabe();
            alleSpiele.remove(sudp);
            if (alleSpiele.size() < 7) {
                Thread t = new Thread(run);
                lock.unlock();
                t.start();
            }
        }
```

The Thread which is started is this Code:

```
public void run() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    while (alleSpiele.size() < 10) {
        alleSpiele.add(new SudokuSpiel());
    }
}
```

My Question:
How can I implement Locks so it works, I always get Exceptions and Errors with this approach...

Comment: Can a Queue be used instead of a List?

Comment: @AndrewS Only Lists are allowed.

Comment: @Kayaman Most of the times IllegalStateMonitorException.

Comment: What class is `lock`? What kind of exceptions are you getting? Include them in the question: edit the question and answer **both** my questions by including all relevant code. You'll also find out what causes `IllegalMonitorStateException` with an easy search.

Comment: @Kayaman Lock is a ReentrantLock.

Comment: The idea behind locking is *mutual exclusion*. You only have one thread locking and unlocking the lock, so it doesn't do anything. It needs to be shared between threads so that when one thread has the lock and another tries to lock it, it waits. Exceptions aren't your (only) problem, your logic is not correct. Recommended reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Comment: In addition to the points said by @Kayaman, it should be obvious that lock and unlock actions must be paired. Locking once at the beginning of the program but unlocking in a loop makes no sense.